# cannot reach my laravel site on 8000 port on aws ec2 ubuntu 18.04 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, ubuntu-18.04

I am a beginner for `AWS`. I have launched `AWS`, `EC2`, `ubuntu 18.04` instance. Now i need to launch my `laravel` application with a sub domain with port 8000 as `laravel` default port is 8000. i have created a sub domain with inbound rule for port 8000. But i cannot browse the sub domain When i try to browse with port 8000. but without port 8000, it works.

http://subdomain.mydomain.com - this works,
http://subdomain.mydomain.com:8000 - cannot reach

Comment: I could run my site without using port.